# Saving a cross-validation trained model in Scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, cross-validation

I have trained a model in `scikit-learn` using `Cross-Validation` and `Naive Bayes` classifier. How can I persist this model to later run against new instances?

Here is simply what I have, I can get the `CV` scores but I don't know how to have access to the trained model

```
gnb = GaussianNB() 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(gnb, data_numpy[0],data_numpy[1], cv=10)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

cross_val_score doesn't changes your estimator, and it will not return fitted estimator. It just returns score of estimator of cross validation.

To fit your estimator - you should call fit on it explicitly with provided dataset.
To save (serialize) it - you can use pickle:

```
# To fit your estimator
gnb.fit(data_numpy[0], data_numpy[1])
# To serialize
import pickle
with open('our_estimator.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(gnb, fid)
# To deserialize estimator later
with open('our_estimator.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    gnb = pickle.load(fid)
```

Comment: I want to fit the estimator using cross validation, I mean to calculate the parameters using the cross validation. So how can I do that?

Comment: @alivar, CV fits different classifiers on different subsets of dataset, and then averages their scores. That's why there is no such notion as fitting estimator with cross_validation. Basically you should just fit estimator on complete dataset.
 
If you want to find hyperparameters for estimator - Look at [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV)

Comment: GridSearchCV was great but I can't find the theta and sigma vectors after training. BTE let me explain my problem again so you may have a better solution for me or correct me. I have a dataset with labeled instances which I can use to train a classifier, then I have to run the classifier on new instances which I don't know the true class category for. Now, what I am concerned about is that if I simply train a GaussianNB using the labeled data-set I am not sure if it gives me a classifier with the same accuracy which when using CV I get. Does that make sense?

Comment: @alivar, if you'll train estimator on full dataset, instead of k-1 parts inside K-fold cv, it will give better results (not worse). It's common practice to learn estimator on full dataset after it has shown sufficient score in CV.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken about multioutput.RegressorChain()'s internals, but I believe you could supply RegressorChain w/ the same cv and run RegressorChain w/ just one dv.

That would allow you to use .predict() as you'd like.